# Events of supremum and infimum of random variables

Tags: measure-theory

Let $Y_n$ be a sequence of real random variables, and let $c \in \mathbb{R}$ be some constant. I know that $\inf_n Y_n$ and $\sup_n Y_n$ are also random variables. I'm interested in trying to represent events of these sup and inf random variables as unions or intersections of events of $Y_n$. I've come up with the following relations intuitively, but I'm not a 100% sure that they are true:

- $\{\sup_n Y_n > c\} = \bigcup_n \{Y_n > c\}$
- $\{\inf_n Y_n > c\} = \bigcap_n \{Y_n > c\}$

and

- $\{\sup_n Y_n < c\} = \bigcap_n \{Y_n < c\}$
- $\{\inf_n Y_n < c\} = \bigcup_n \{Y_n < c\}$

Additionally, if these are true, in which cases can the $>$ or $<$ be relaxed into $\geq$ or $\leq$?

Answer (score 1):

$\{\text{inf}_n Y_n > c \}= \bigcup_k \bigcap_n \{Y_n > c +\frac{1}{k} \}$. And similar for $\{\text{sup}_n Y_n < c\}$.

$\{\text{inf}_n Y_n \geq c \}=\bigcap_n \{Y_n \geq c \}$ is true, but $\{\text{sup}_n Y_n \geq c\} =\bigcap_k \bigcup_n \{Y_n \geq c -\frac{1}{k} \}$ and similar for $\{\text{inf}_n Y_n \leq c \}$.